# Why is hydrogen no longer considered a colossal fire hazard?

Tags: hydrogen-fuel

I thought after the Hindenburg catastrophe large-scale hydrogen-powered vehicles are no longer considered something safe and worthy of investment. However, it's gaining a lot of traction lately: cars, planes, trains... Has the issue of hydrogen's explosiveness been resolved? Or is it going to last till another major tragedy?

Answer (score 4):

Hydrogen still is a fire/explosion hazard. Nothing about the fundamentals of hydrogen have changed.

People still need to be careful regarding liquid lead-acid batteries in cars because of the potential for hydrogen to accumulate within the batteries or to be released by the batteries.

What has changed regarding hydrogen is people's awareness and technology. The hydrogen storage technology and safety technology used by the Hindenburg were primitive compared to what is currently available. People are aware of the history of hydrogen and it usage and they are exercising more care regarding design, manufacturing, materials, exposure to heat, shock reduction, ventilation, static electricity, proximity or naked flames or sparks, etc.

Previously, hydrogen had to be combusted to use its energy. Now, fuel cells can utilize hydrogen to generate electricity, which is safer. See what Japanese car maker Toyota is doing with the [Mirai](https://www.toyota.com.au/mirai) - it's an electric vehicle that is powered by hydrogen.

The [hydrogen tank](https://www.toyota.com/mirai/features/hydrogen_tank/3002/3003), storage capacity is 5.6 kg. That gives a driving range of 650 km. The tank is comprised of a polymer liner, carbon fiber reinforce polymer middle section and a fiber glass reinforced surface section.

Answer (score 1):

Hindenburg is a disaster waiting to happen. It had a soft fabric with hydrogen inside. If that fabric breaks (for example due to a bird colliding to it), the hydrogen starts to leak. A spark and you have ignition, resulting in a massive fireball. Tanks in cars won't be punctured so easily.

Besides, we have Hindenburgs in air today. They are weather balloons. Hydrogen is used, because helium is a scarce resource that shouldn't be wasted. The difference is that no humans are onboard, so if it explodes, it won't cause any actual damage.

However, hydrogen in cars is a completely different matter. A typical car has very little of it, because fuel cells and electric motors are so efficient. In fact, about 5.6 kg, as the other answer explains. That's 66.9 cubic meters. At lower flammability limit of 4%, if everything leaks it can cause a room with size of 1672 cubic meters to explode -- assuming the tank was full. A parking hall with space for 40 cars is large enough that if all of the hydrogen from one car leaks, it still won't cause an explosion because the space where the hydrogen can expand is so large. And even if the parking hall is a very small one with space for maybe 15 vehicles, it probably has very good ventilation.

But will that explosion happen? Most likely, no. Firstly, it's extraordinarily unlikely that all of the hydrogen would leak so fast. Secondly, cars are not used in sealed spaces. Every parking hall has to have a very good ventilation system, or else people would die inside due to all of the carbon monoxide produced by gasoline engines.

Outdoors, it's not an issue. The hydrogen will dissipate so fast it really won't explode. Actually, outdoors gasoline is a far more major hazard, because it's a liquid that can continue spilling into the fire from the tank, as opposed to gas that would dissipate fast. Also, a typical gasoline vehicle has maybe 56 liters of gasoline, containing 1800 megajoules of energy. The 5.6 kg hydrogen contains only 670 megajoules of energy so smaller fire if all of that burned -- but it won't start to burn except maybe in very extraordinary circumstances.

What about electric vehicles then? They have batteries that have all the reactants for a massive fire. That fire is not limited by oxygen like gasoline or hydrogen fires are, because the reactants needed are all inside the battery. So if you try to smother that fire, tough luck, you won't succeed.

I'd say that in typical parking hall the most dangerous cars are electric vehicles (due to easily flammable batteries and due to the fire not being limited by the amount of oxygen), and liquid petroleum gas (propane) vehicles.

LPG is dangerous because it's heavier than air, so it can accumulate in parking halls. Hydrogen is lighter than air, so it will easily dissipate.

For planes, the only safety issue in hydrogen is if all of it is lost mid-flight far away from airfields, maybe over an ocean. Making a landing in the middle of an ocean won't be very safe... Kerosene fueled planes at least probably wouldn't leak the fuel so fast because it's not pressurized.

However, planes maybe could use liquid hydrogen instead of pressurized hydrogen. If that's the case, it has exactly the same safety properties as kerosene, except it's so cold you won't want to touch it. Leaks would be slow, like kerosene leaks are.

Comment: Why didn't Hindenburg's hydrogen dissipate?

Comment: It ignited right when it was dissipating. That kind of failure mode isn't really reasonable for high-strength hydrogen tanks, that develop small leaks as opposed to large leaks, so the hydrogen simply has enough time to dissipate. If you have a soft balloon filled with hydrogen, when it breaks it develops a huge leak, so huge that the hydrogen can ignite when it's actively dissipating.